# Change with jQuery a cell of a table created with JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, xhtml

From within a `xhtml` page created with JSF, I need to use JavaScript / jQuery for changing the content of a cell of a table. I know how to assign a unique id to the `div` containing the table, and to the `tbody`. I can also assign unique class names to the `div` itself and to the target column. The target row is identified by the `data-rk` attribute.

```
<div id="tabForm:centerTabView:personsTable" class="ui-datatable ui-widget personsTable">
    <table role="grid">
        <tbody id="tabForm:centerTabView:personsTable_data" >
            <tr data-rk="2" >
                <td ... />
                <td class="lastNameCol" role="gridcell">
                    <div> To Be Edited </div>
                </td>
                <td ... />
            </tr>
            <tr ... />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried with many combinations of different jQuery selectors, but I am really lost. I need to search my target row and my target column inside that particular div or inside that particular table, because the xhtml page may contain other tables with different unique ids (and accidentally with the same row and column ids).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$("#tabForm\\:centerTabView\\:personsTable tr[data-rk=2] td.lastNameCol div").text("edited");
```

Or if `personsTable` is unique enough in the current view

```js
$("[id$=personsTable] tr[data-rk=2] td.lastNameCol div").text("edited");
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. These two lines alone represent an almost complete tutorial on selectors! Btw, what's the reason for the dollar sign after id in the second line?

Comment: It's the "Attribute-Ends-With" selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle for your new html code

[Fiddle without colon](http://jsfiddle.net/c26uv/4/)

[Fiddle with Colon](http://jsfiddle.net/c26uv/3/)

Comment: I have given the solution as a fiddle. can you check it out.

Comment: No. The row is identified by the data-rk attribute. Also note that row id and column id are not enough. I need somehow to search inside the external id or at least inside the tbody tag because they are identified with unique ids.

Comment: i updated the new fiddle. The problem is with your id of the body i guess. You should escape that using `\\\` also.

Comment: i have added both the fiddles. my fiddle replace all the cells, but you can narrow down by using some class specifier for the div's. is that fine.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with updating the exact row's cell by considering the `data-rk` attribute.